# how to fix this crash : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each element of 'value' must be a valid managed object

Tags: android, realm

When I make an object called MyLatLng extends RealmObject then make the list of this object called saved path,I tried to set the saved path but I got this crash .

```
  mRealm.beginTransaction();
    TrackingInfo trackingInfo=mRealm.createObject(TrackingInfo.class);
    trackingInfo.setSavedDistance(savedDistance);
    trackingInfo.setOrder_id(order_id);
    trackingInfo.setSavedDuration(savedDuration);
    trackingInfo.setSavedPath(savedpath);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

i got the crash in line before last one ..
how can i fix this error ?
thanx in advance ..

Comment: what is savedpath and what is the code behind setSavedPath

Comment: this is saved path  RealmList<MySavedLatLng>savedpath=new RealmList<>();

Comment: please provide the class MySavedLatLng

Comment: public class MySavedLatLng extends RealmObject {
    public MySavedLatLng() {}
   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;
}with getter and setter

Comment: have you tried to remove the contractor for MySavedLatLng

Comment: well the elements in saved path aren't managed, then.

Comment: how can i manage it ?

Comment: I tried to remove constructor but it couse problem :(

Comment: Please also show how and where savedPath comes from.